# Replace space between a pattern <>

Tags: regex, hive

I have requirement to parse XML tags. But some tags are appeared with blanks like below.

So basically I want to remove blank character inside the XML tag using regex.

```
<Employee   >< Name>ABC</Name><Age>21</Age  ></Employee>
```

In the tags of Employee, Name and Age space are present either in front or back of tags but between `<>`.

So basically I want to get output like this.

```
<Employee><Name>ABC</Name><Age>21</Age></Employee>
```

Note : space can be multiple not single occurrence between the `<>`.

Please help me on this providing regex to do this.

Thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An expression that might capture our undesired spaces would be for instance similar to:

```
<\s*(\/)?\s*(\S+?)\s*>
```

and we might be able to make a replacement with: `<$1$2>`.

#### [Please see the demo here.](https://regex101.com/r/GJnROn/1/)

Edit:

```
<\s*(\/)?\s*(\S+?)\s*(\/)?>
```

and our code might look like:

```
regexp_replace(str,'<\\s*(\\/)?\\s*(\\S+?)\\s*(\\/)?>','<$1$2$3>')
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q9SEtH/1/)

#### Advice

[leftjoin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2700344/leftjoin) advises that:

> For Hive use double backslash, it works fine:
>
> ```
> regexp_replace(str,'<\\s*(\\/)?\\s*(\\S+?)\\s*>','<$1$2>')
> ```

Comment: For Hive use double backslash, it works fine: `regexp_replace(str,'<\\s*(\\/)?\\s*(\\S+?)\\s*>','<$1$2>')`

Comment: Hi @leftjoin , Thanks for your update. This works fine. But when I get string like <Type />. This is an empty tag contains space at back. I want to remove that as well. Can you please provide regex for that as well.                                 `code` regexp_replace("<Type   />"'<\\s*(\\/)?\\s*(\\S+?)\\s*>','<$1$2>') this should return <Type/>. Appreciate your help on this. Thanks

Comment: @ungalVicky Well, this is Emma's answer. Why dont you ask her? I can help of couse. Add one more group to the regexp for slash and possible spaces before and after. Like this: select regexp_replace(str,'<\\s*(\\/)?\\s*(\\S+?)\\s*(\\/)?\\s*>','<$1$2$3>')

Comment: @Emma You was faster :)